# How to tell what context you are running under in C#?

Tags: c#, windows

How do I to tell what context an application is running under?

That is, user context, system context, etc... Is there some code I can run to tell? [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) or something?

Comment: note: I realize that it should be self evident but i really am looking for a programmatic solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the .NET class `ServiceSecurityContext.Current` -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext.aspx

E.g. The following example from MSDN shows you how to use this class

```
// Run this method from within a method protected by the PrincipalPermissionAttribute
// to see the security context data, including the primary identity.
public void WriteServiceSecurityContextData(string fileName)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        // Write the primary identity and Windows identity. The primary identity is derived from
        // the credentials used to authenticate the user. The Windows identity may be a null string.
        sw.WriteLine("PrimaryIdentity: {0}", ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name);
        sw.WriteLine("WindowsIdentity: {0}", ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name);
        sw.WriteLine();
        // Write the claimsets in the authorization context. By default, there is only one claimset
        // provided by the system. 
        foreach (ClaimSet claimset in ServiceSecurityContext.Current.AuthorizationContext.ClaimSets)
        {
            foreach (Claim claim in claimset)
            {
                // Write out each claim type, claim value, and the right. There are two
                // possible values for the right: "identity" and "possessproperty". 
                sw.WriteLine("Claim Type = {0}", claim.ClaimType);
                sw.WriteLine("\t Resource = {0}", claim.Resource.ToString());
                sw.WriteLine("\t Right = {0}", claim.Right);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347790.aspx

Comment: Hi JD, im getting a null reference on ServiceSecurityContext.Current.. any ideas why? Im running from a console app.

Comment: @Grant: That means your console app is probably running as anonymous. You can check this by investigating the `System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext` class at runtime

Comment: Thanks JD. Ive also tried running from a windows app and its anonymouse too. What does this mean? I am currently logged on to a Windows domain from Windows 7. Wouldnt i have a current identity?

Answer (score 0):

You could check on

```
var isAnonymous = ServiceSecurityContext.Anonymous.IsAnonymous;
```

to avoid `null` on `ServiceSecurityContext.Current`